# Возможно ли программно сделать так, чтобы MainActivity не открывалась на экране, но выполнялась программа?

Tags: java, android-studio

```
public final void alarm() {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2820 * 1000, pending);
}

public static class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
      context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Код прекрасно выполняется. AlarmManager запускает его в определенное время. Но, сразу MainActivity открывается на экране поверх всех остальных приложений, например набора номера телефона или общения в Facebook. Как сделать так, чтобы она не открывалась поверх используемых в данный момент приложений, а оставалась скрытой? Пока сам не разобрался. Прошу помощи, как это сделать.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться. Моего опыта пока-что маловато.

Comment: На самом деле, там всё не так сложно. Если будут какие-то конкретные вопросы, задавайте отдельным вопросом (:

Comment: Попробуйте setContentView убрать строку

Comment: Спасибо. Если будут проблемы - обращусь еще раз.

Comment: К сожалению проблема осталась. Не разобрался.

Comment: Закоментирование setContentView обваливает Android

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в Интернете вариант, спасибо тому, кто выложил

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";

public void curtail(){
new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {//10000 - 10 sec, 1000 - step 1 sec

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences
                (MainActivity.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        finish();
    }
}
        .start();
```

}